# insert row with datetime index to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetime index:

```
time                count  day hour  minute  label
2018-06-07 00:25:00 207    7.0 0.0   25.0    177.0
2018-06-07 00:55:00 187    7.0 0.0   55.0    150.0
2018-06-07 01:25:00 194    7.0 1.0   25.0    165.0
2018-06-07 01:55:00 176    7.0 1.0   55.0    175.0
2018-06-07 02:25:00 195    7.0 2.0   25.0    172.0
-> add new datetime record record here
```

and I'm trying to add some new records but I get:

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2018-06-07 01:55:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)] not an index
# this happen even if row exists or not
```

I just want to add a 30 minutes interval record, my code is something like

```
last_date = recent_posts.iloc[[-1]].index
last_date = last_date + timedelta(minutes=30)

recent_posts.iloc[[last_date]] = # bla #bla

# What I may be doing wrong?
```

Comment: You are looking for `last_date` DatetimeIndex which is not in the dataframe.

Comment: it is! when "recent_posts.iloc[[-1]].index" gives the last element, however, I think should matter is index doest not exists, I want to insert a new row!
correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way to insert a new record would be:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=[last_date]))
```

Example:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                   count    day hour    minute  label
time                    
2018-06-07 00:25:00 207 7.0 0.0 25.0    177.0
2018-06-07 00:55:00 187 7.0 0.0 55.0    150.0
```

To add an element, use [.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=[last_date]))
```

Output:

```
                     count  day  hour  label  minute
2018-06-07 00:25:00  207.0  7.0   0.0  177.0    25.0
2018-06-07 00:55:00  187.0  7.0   0.0  150.0    55.0
2018-06-07 01:25:00    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
```

As you can see, it adds a new record with the defined index and since we did not specify values for other columns, they are `NaN`

You can specify the values for one or more columns with a `dict` like this:

```
data = {'hour':10} 
df.append(pd.DataFrame(data, index=[last_date]))
```

Output:

```
                     count  day  hour  label  minute
2018-06-07 00:25:00  207.0  7.0   0.0  177.0    25.0
2018-06-07 00:55:00  187.0  7.0   0.0  150.0    55.0
2018-06-07 01:25:00    NaN  NaN   10.0    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Super thansk Harv!  Examples I've seen almost always use concat or altering the index directly

Comment: Glad I could help. @Freddy

Comment: I have seen in few places that `append` make a copy of the dataframe, and that a more efficient way to do it is with `.loc[]`, but I get an error `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns` when I use `df.loc[last_date] = data`. Do you know how to get it working this way? Thank you

Comment: @PS It seems that you need to assign the object created with `.append` to another variable as `.append` does do in-place modification so data is not saved. This was not clear from your post.

Comment: @Confounded I have added the link of the official docs. It is impossible to put every aspect of the function in the answer, hence the official doc link. Glad you figured that one out yourself.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the new value with e.g. df['2018-06-07 01:25:00']? It gives KeyError even if pd.to_datetime is used on index afterwards.